# See content of sourced script

Tags: bash, shell, source

When I source a script in bash, is there a possibility to look at the script, that I just sourced, without accessing the script itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on the shell trace (`set -x`), and see what statements are executed as you *source* the script.

A comment by @jthill notes that the verbose option (`set -v`) also is useful.  From the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> **`-v`**
> Print shell input lines as they are read.
>
> **`-x`**
> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are executed. The value of the `PS4` variable is expanded and the resultant value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

It depends on what you want.  I've never found the analogous `verbose` mode in `csh` useful, but someone found it useful enough to implement *there* first.

Comment: There's also `set -v` to see statements as they're read.

Answer (score 1):

If you can `source` a script, you can read it.  `cat /path/to/script` will display `script`'s contents.

Answer (score 0):

I found this is not possible. The best one can do, is using

```
set
```

It will show all set variables and all functions defined. If the sourced script was a set of functions, it can be reconstructed, but it's not clear which functions were called and which were not. At least `set` gives you all the variables and their values that are set in a given session.